# prove the validity of unit step function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like some help to understand better a specific part of the proof. The goal of the proof is to prove the $u(t)$ definition.

By the definition of a generalized function:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)u(t)dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)dt$$

Step 1: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)u(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{0} f(t)u(t)dt+\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)u(t)dt= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)dt $$

Step 2: $$\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(t)u(t)dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)[1-u(t)]dt$$

I do not understand the derivation of RHS of step 2. How?

Comment: From Step $1$, we have $\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(t)u(t)dt = -\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)u(t)dt+  \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)dt$. Now factor.

Comment: well, i only understand this: $\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(t)u(t)dt=-\int_0^{-\infty}f(t)u(t)dt = -\int_0^{\infty}f(-t)u(-t)(-dt) = \int_0^{\infty}f(-t)u(-t)dt\,$, which does not match with yours :/

Comment: That is not even needed. Just do simple algebra from step 1. Move the $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)u(t)dt$ to the RHS and then factor.